# Could I have a Failed HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, freeze, chkdsk

I have a computer that's been running not too well lately. I took it to Staples and after keeping it over night they said my hard drive is failing and I need a new one. I ran disk check, hard drive checks out fine. I ran Space Monger and it was able to index my entire hard drive successfully. The PC still boots and runs (although it freezes sometimes if it's not in safe mode).

Their diagnosis just sounded off to me and they couldn't really elaborate past "The hard drive is failing." Could they be correct and how could I double check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your drive has SMART support (It most likely does), run a test and get the results. Post the results here if you are unsure whether the test results are a pass or not.

A drive can fail a SMART test and yet be working perfectly fine, the whole point of SMART is that it is a pre-fail warning system.

However it is strange they wouldn't tell you their methodology.

Comment: This is a 4 year old hp, it doesn't give many details but it says:

`CPU Test - Passed
Connection Test - Passed
Boot Test - Passed
SMART Test - Passed
Memory Test - Passed`

So it doesn't look like it's the HDD?

Comment: That's not the SMART test results.

Comment: There should be a hard drive fitness test in the bios, did you run that?

Comment: Wow alright that was quick. Gets about 2 seconds in then says Value 7 (Completed with the read element of the test failed). Thanks so much for the help!